# IOS: delegate of many scrollViews

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, uiscrollview

I have this code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
[self performSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];



}

- (void) scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];



if (scrollView == scrollV){
    NSLog(@"scroll di scrollV"); 
}
}
```

I don't understand why it don't print in console "scroll di scrollV", I set delegate for scrollV, but it don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want this?:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:) withObject:scrollView afterDelay:0.01];
```

You weren't passing the `scrollView` object so the `if (scrollView == scrollV)` would never hit unless `scrollV` was `nil`, which I'm guessing it isn't.